# Restart srvany when child process gets killed

Tags: windows, service, console, registry, srvany

I've created a service, which is a plain console application running via `srvany.exe`. It was set up to immediately restart when destroyed. Here's the script:

```
sc delete "Test Service"
sc create "Test Service" binpath= "C:\Windows\System32\srvany.exe" start= auto
sc failure "Test Service" reset= 86400 actions= restart/0
sc description "Test Service" Blah
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Test Service\Parameters" /v Application /d "C:\<path>\testserv.exe"
sc start "Test Service"
```

It's created properly, and restarts if I kill `srvany` with `taskmgr`. But when I kill `testserv`, `srvany` keeps running, effectively ruining my plans for immediate restart.

Is there a (either console or registry) key for `srvany` to exit when its child process gets killed? If not, is there any other simple ways to accomplish this task (without [writing a service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While srvany will gladly start your application as a service, it does not monitor the spawned process in any way to achieve what you want. We have a competing software called AlwaysUp; [read more](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html) about srvany's shortcomings there.

Answer (score 2):

The article in CoreTech's answer is from AlwaysUp which itself is a paid application. If you are looking for a free alternative that monitors child processes, try [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/).